# Pyplot: Plotting [Lists of [(Lists of Tuples)]]

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, tuples

Suppose you have a list of length "i", containing tuples or lists of tuples with length "j" (such that a singular tuple will have j=1), each of which contain "k" elements.

I am attempting to make a plotting routine such that there are "i" subplots, each with "j" lines.

This is what I have so far, where "rows" and "cols" are pre-determined integers to determine the subplot layout:

```
for i in range(0, len(x_lolots)):
    for j in range(0, len(x_lolots[i])):
        for k in range(0, len(x_lolots[i][j])):
            plt.ion()
            plt.subplot(rows, cols, (i+1))
            plt.plot(x_lolots[i][j][k], y_lolots[i][j][k])
```

This gives me the correct arrangement of subplots, but shows no lines.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.plot` takes 1d-arrays as input, so the last `for` loop over `k` is not necessary.

```
for i in range(0, len(x_lolots)):
    for j in range(0, len(x_lolots[i])):
        plt.ion()
        plt.subplot(rows, cols, (i+1))
        plt.plot(x_lolots[i][j], y_lolots[i][j])
```